# detach process in bash for loop

Tags: bash

I often find myself wanting to look at a bunch of plots in a directory.  I typically do something like:

```
for PLT in *.png; do bash -c "display ${PLT} &" ; done
```

since

```
for PLT in *.png; do display ${PLT} & ; done  #doesn't work :-(
```

Is there an easier/less ugly/better idiom for this sort of thing?
I have also tried enclosing the commmand in parenthesis, but that doesn't work either (it only opens one plot)...

```
for PLT in *.png; do ( display ${PLT} ) ; done
```

**EDIT**

Note that I am working in an interactive terminal.  If I write a script and break the second for loop into multiple lines, it works just fine...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the semicolon after your &:

```
for PLT in *.png; do display ${PLT} & done
```

Also, using "${PLT}" is a good practice just in case your filenames have spaces in them.

Comment: Brilliant!  Why does the semicolon cause a syntax error when it is typically necessary?

Comment: Just shell syntax.  Both ; and & are line terminators so the ; is ending an empty line, which is taken as a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks again, I generally don't enclose my variables in double quotes because I consider spaces in filenames to be bad practice ... But, you're probably right about that too ...

Comment: It is bad practice, but it's not one that everybody follows so it's just a bit of insurance in case you're working with other people's data.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can do this with [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs).

```
ls *.png | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 10 display
```

Either option might be a little safer, depending on how many png files you need to process.

Comment: neither of your examples will work with files containing spaces. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: that breaks it entirely, since ls output is not \0 terminated.

Comment: It worked when I tested it... although I didn't put much effort into the test.